# PHP Percent calculator of 2 values

Tags: javascript, php, css

Did anyone knows how to calculate percent of 2 numbers,

Those 2 numbers, they automaticaly calculate percent, what is bigger:
[image]

Can PHP script do it? to calculate etc:

```
$1 = '1342';
$2 = '5436';
$result = ??
```

I want to get the % of this 2 numbers, so i can put it in css progress bar... this image is not from my site :)

Sorry for bad english, i am looking for this very long, i think this is very simple thing, but if you dont know that, that is big to you :D

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some basic maths:

```
$var1 = 1342;
$var2 = 5436;

$var1share = $var1 / ($var1 + $var2); // 0.197.. => 19.7... %
$var2share = $var2 / ($var1 + $var2); // 0.802.. => 80.2... %
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i really appreciate this, but i get output like this: 0.19799350840956 
0.80200649159044 Is possible to have without 0. ? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah but value will sometime be 10 but sometime 100000 :/

Comment: @dognose He might be complaining about the number of decimal places.

Comment: @McFilip The results will always range between 0.0 and 1.0 - otherwise your cpu is broken. Therefore it is save to multiply it with 100 in order to get the percentage value.

Comment: Yeah but i need this in etc 19.7, no in 0.197 becouse i use it for css, width: 19.7% ... :/ but value is sometime 10 and sometime 100000 if its * 100 sometime will be 0.00197 and sometime 197.000 am i right?

Comment: I don't get your point. The orignal values do NOT mater anymore. The calculation above will ensure: `$var1share + $var2share === 1` - therefore each variable is `<= 1`, or multiplied with 100 `<= 100 (%)`

Comment: I know, you wrote the right script, but it shows 0.197 i need 19.7 in raw.. :/

Comment: @McFilip Then multiply the result with 100!